# comtypes internal method fails on LP_BSTR

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, comtypes

I'm trying to access the .olb files that ship with ArcGIS10.1 using the **comtypes** module. Some of the .olb files work (esriGeometry.olb) and some of them don't (esriSystem.olb), and some of them work some of the time (esriSearch.olb).

The following code

```
from comtypes.client import GetModule
olb_path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.1\\com\\esriSystem.olb'
m = GetModule(path)
```

raises this traceback and exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    test3()
  File "D:\Data\MatthewPlourde\JAMES\gis_tools\tool.py", line 139, in test3
    m = GetModule(path)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 112, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 188, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 26, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_5E1F7BC3_67C5_4AEE_8EC6_C4B73AAC42ED_0_10_1.py", line 5705, in <module>
    ( ['in'], POINTER(_midlSAFEARRAY(POINTER(BSTR))), 'pParameters' ),
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\safearray.py", line 18, in _midlSAFEARRAY
    sa_type = _make_safearray_type(itemtype)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\comtypes\safearray.py", line 53, in _make_safearray_type
    raise TypeError(itemtype)
TypeError: <class 'comtypes.errorinfo.LP_BSTR'>
```

Apparently `comtypes.safearray._make_safearray_type` doesn't know what to do with `<class 'comtypes.errorinfo.LP_BSTR'>`. If there's anyone out there using ArcGIS10.1, I'd be grateful to know whether you can reproduce this error, and especially grateful if you know the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution [posted](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43583-10.1-beta-and-comtypes) on the ArcGIS forums. It simply involves modifying `automation.py` in the **comtypes** source. Add the entry `POINTER(BSTR): VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR` to the `_ctype_to_vartype` dictionary.

After this, all the .olb's load.

Comment: also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/arcobjects-comtypes-at-10-1

Answer (score 0):

I too, am having this exact error and I can't get past it.  If you find out what happens please update this.  The only thing I can find is something saying that there may be mixing 32 bit with 64 bit libs.
(also, I don't see where I can send a reply to your question... only an answer.  I don't use stackexchange much)

Let me add something that may help you, this was taken from: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/15848-ArcMap-10-ArcObjects-and-Python-very-cool-but-help-with-a-couple-of-problems

```
import logging
# grab rootlogger
_loggy = logging.getLogger()
_loggy.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
_loggy.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("derpdebug.log"))
import os
import comtypes.client
# change com_dir to whatever it is for you
com_dir = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\com'
coms = [os.path.join(com_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(com_dir) if os.path.splitext(x)[1].upper() == '.OLB']
map(comtypes.client.GetModule, coms)
# check add whatever you want here.
import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI
import comtypes.gen.esriGeodatabase

print dir(comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI)
```

Then I just did:
grep -v ^Release derpdebug.log >readable.log

Comment: Thanks. Turn's out there's a solution.